# Where did the sanhedrin get its power from?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, beit-din-court

I guess we always assume that the power invested in the Sanhedrin comes from "Lo Sasur". However, this posuk is talking about either the Kohanim, or the shofet.
Now, I know originally the cohen gadol sat, but 1) why was that neccesary, and 2) eventually that went away too. So where did their power come from?

Comment: Can you source your many assumptions? (eg. "this posuk is talking about either the Kohanim, or the shofet" "originally the cohen gadol sat" "eventually that went away too") Where is "Lo Sasur" found? Deut 28:14?

Comment: Lo Sasur is from Parshas Shoftim (Deut 17:11). The context of the pasuk is quite clear "You will come to levite priests and the shofet who will be in your day...you will do as they rule...you shall not turn what what they tell you..."

Comment: "*Shofet*" means judge. Are you asking how we know there need to be 71 of them?

Comment: I believe that the original concept of having 70 judges for Sanhedrin (there was various Sanedrin groups. BTW) comes from this past week's parsha (Beha'alotcha) where G-d asks Moshe to appoint 70 judges to assist him.

Comment: I'm asking because somebody is claiming to me that the pasuk of Lo Sasur is referring to the cohanim, who are supposed to be the guardians and teachers of our faith, who were, for the most part, the tzedukim, and the concept of a Sanhedrin is a rabbinical corruption, with no source in the Torah.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  When I read your question I understood it to be asking how _we_ know that there is a Sanhedrin. In light of your comments, do you mean to ask, instead, how we would disprove the Sadducee's possible alternate reading?

Comment: Well, according to them, its not an alternate reading...its the pshat..and the rabbis came and "corrupted" it, usurping the power from the cohanim.

Comment: @DanF - I was about to write this as an answer - but I think that you should. _the original concept of having 70 judges for Sanhedrin (there was various Sanedrin groups. BTW) comes from this past week's parsha (Beha'alotcha) where G-d asks Moshe to appoint 70 judges to assist him_